# Ubuntu wont boot after fresh installation

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04

I installed ubuntu on a new mlaptop, everything went okay, I restarted the system, and then I got this screen
[image: screen]

and it won't start anymore, what should I do

screenshoot I tried to restart it few times but its the same?

When i go to the grub menu i have this screen

[image: grub menu screen]

not sure why i have two ubuntu with linux, is this normal?

Comment: Two things come to mind. 1. Did you verify the ISO you made the Live Media from? 2. Did you follow the official tutorial? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Those entries in grub are for an older kernel, and recovery mode for each kernel.  Have you tried recovery mode (both)?  Do you have video hardware with proprietary drivers (Nvidia?)?

Comment: YES I HAVE nVIDIA

Comment: i didnt verify, is it nesseasry?

Comment: Did you get it from the Ubuntu website? More than likely, it's fine if you did. However, large files can be corrupted during transfer. Me personally, I have run into the issue where the ISO downloaded was corrupted and I couldn't get the OS to install correctly because of missing or corrupt files. Verifying the image checks integrity and ensures that the image is not missing anything.

Comment: i did from ubuntu, how i can unistall this one and reinstall new?

Comment: but how to unistall current system?

Comment: 1. You can simply overwrite the previously installed Ubuntu (install into the same location); 2. With nvidia graphics you may need the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` (which you get via the recovery mode or manually at the grub menu).

Comment: but when i insert usb into laptop and turn it on i dont recieve install screen

Comment: Is your BIOS set to boot from usb first?

Comment: yes, but now my system wont boot anymore, even if i try recovery mode, not sure what to do

Comment: i installed 23 version instead 22.04 and now everything works like a charm, thanksss

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's normal. In fact, these different boot options are all for the same Ubuntu system.

You have two entries for each version of the Linux kernel you have installed. [Recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) is for fixing issues with your boot process, also called "single-user" mode. The other one is the normal mode you typically use.

And the reason it shows multiple Linux kernel versions is so that if the latest one causes any issues, you can select a previous one that was working well.

Later on, as new Linux versions are installed on your system, this list will grow. I believe it keeps 5-10 of the most recent Linux kernel versions, and it deletes old ones.